# pattern matching (codejam round 1A previous year) solution not working

Tags: c++, pattern-matching

I am trying previous year's codejam question of round 1A

[link to question](https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/codejam/round/000000000019fd74/00000000002b3034#problem)

i have submitted this code(start reading from main method, for ease)-

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

#define range(t) for (int i = 0; i < t; i++)
#define rangeG(i, t) for (i = 0; i < t; i++)
#define printVec(vec)      \
    for (auto c : vec)     \
    {                      \
        cout << c << endl; \
    }

vector<string> separate(string s)
{
    vector<string> result;
    range(s.size())
    {
        if (s[i] == '*')
        {
            string temp = s.substr(0, i + 1);
            if (temp.size() > 1)
            {
                result.push_back(temp);
            }
            s = s.substr(i, s.size());
            i = 0;
        }
        else if (i == (s.size() - 1))
        {
            string temp = s.substr(0, i + 1);
            result.push_back(temp);
            s = s.substr(i, s.size());
        }
    }
    return result;
}

void removeAsterisk(string &s)
{
    s.erase(remove(s.begin(), s.end(), '*'), s.end());
}

bool setStart(string s, string &start)
{
    bool possible = 1;
    removeAsterisk(s);
    range(min(s.size(), start.size()))
    {
        if (s[i] != start[i])
        {
            possible = 0;
        }
    }

    if (possible)
    {
        if (s.size() >= start.size())
        {
            start = s;
        }
    }

    return possible;
}

bool setEnd(string s, string &end)
{
    bool possible = 1;
    removeAsterisk(s);
    range(min(s.size(), end.size()))
    {
        if (s[s.size() - 1 - i] != end[end.size() - 1 - i])
        {
            possible = 0;
        }
    }

    if (possible)
    {
        if (s.size() >= end.size())
        {
            end = s;
        }
    }

    return possible;
}

void solve()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    vector<string> allS;
    bool possible = 1;

    string start = "";
    string end = "";
    string middle = "";
    string result = "";

    while (n--)
    {
        string str;
        cin >> str;
        if (count(str.begin(), str.end(), '*') == 0)
        {
            result = str;
        }
        vector<string> temp = separate(str);
        for (string s : temp)
        {
            if (s[0] != '*')
            {
                possible = setStart(s, start);
            }
            if (s[s.size() - 1] != '*')
            {
                possible = setEnd(s, end);
            }
            if (possible && count(s.begin(), s.end(), '*') == 0)
            {
                result = s;
                break;
            }
            if (s[0] == '*' && s[s.size() - 1] == '*')
            {
                removeAsterisk(s);
                middle += s;
            }
        }
    }

    if (possible)
    {
        if (result.size() == 0)
        {
            result = start + middle + end;
        }
        cout << result << "\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "*\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);
    int t = 0;
    cin >> t;
    range(t)
    {
        cout << "Case #" << i + 1 << ": ";
        solve();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

it seems correct to me and i have tested many times for many examples, but it is losing in test set-1(exactly one * (asterisk) character and and always the first character of string). Can anyone tell what's wrong?
you can consider code of first ranked [here](https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/codejam/submissions/000000000019fd74/R2VubmFkeS5Lb3JvdGtldmljaA) (it has all solutions,check only for "pattern matching" task) for help. I know that the wrong answer is an edge case and if it passes test set 1 then it will pass others.